# How to use a tar file( .tgz) in a react application which don't have internet connection

Tags: reactjs

Creating a full stack application - react, asp.net, ms SQL.

I am working for the government company, there we don't have internet in all the development systems, but have a internet in one system which is a ubuntu Operating System, in this system we can download anything but no access for installation. Personal laptops also not allowed in the company.

So, Created a basic setup of reactjs in my personal laptop which has internet which can run a application, the same folders sent through mail and copied in non internet system, so it's working. So the issue is everytime when I need a new npm package, I have to download in my personal internet laptop and copy the same in non internet system which is in my company.

So I have researched little bit and got to know - A new npm package I can download from this link(for example mentioned axios) - https://registry.npmjs.org/axios/0.27.2

So, it will download as a tar file(`somename.tgz`). That package downloaded in ubuntu system which has internet in my company and copied the same file to non internet system.

So now the issue how to use this tar file in my react application?

Mentioning some of the ways I have tried to link this file in my application:

1. Npm install tarfilename
2. Tar tarfilename

But the above options not working,looks like it needs internet to run

Note: working in a non internet system. In ubuntu system which has internet, no application is installed and no access for installation also.

Comment: The `tar` command line utility defiantly requires no internet

Comment: An npm package usually has lots of dependencies, so even if you had a tar file of a package, it would need to download lots of other packages

Comment: Do you have npm in the Ubuntu machine ? If so create folder in there and do ```npm install <package>``` then copy the node_modules folder to the other machine

Comment: Npm is not there. Actually there is no application installed in ubuntu and no access for installation also

Comment: @Celsiuss I tried the tar tarfilename command with internet. Package is linked and it's working.